# Why do I get method is not a function in my jesttest?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

My jest unittest looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import Calculator from "./calculator";

test('test that calculator', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(
            <Calculator></Calculator>
        );
        let tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
        console.log('component=',component.refs);

        // Simulate click on button -> trigger sumCalc()
        ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(component.refs.button);

});
```

When I run the test I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined
```

My react component looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Calculator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.calcSum = this.calcSum.bind(this);
        this.state = {sum: 0};
    }

    calcSum() {
        console.log('this.refs.one=', this.refs.one);
        let s = Number(this.refs.one.value) + Number(this.refs.two.value);
        this.setState({sum: s});
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="number 1" ref="one"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="number 2" ref="two"/>
                <button ref="button" onClick={this.calcSum}>sum</button>
                sum: {this.state.sum}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this error? what am I missing?
The component works when rendered into the DOM but the unit test has issues.

Comment: Please debug: `console.log(tree.props.calcSum)` and post the log...

Comment: it returns :undefined

Comment: it should be `tree.calcSum();`

Comment: You are not passing any `props` ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`component.toJSON()` returns a JSON not a JavaScript object. Moreover `calcSum` is not a prop, instead it is a method defined on your component class.

Hence you could use `getInstance()` method to manually invoke `calcSum`.

Try this:

```
  const component = renderer.create(<Calculator />);

  component.getInstance().calcSum();
```

Now you can see that `console.log` output from `calcSum`.